# Why it take time to insert a records in to databse in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two tables first is for `post` and second table is for for `user`. In table post have user_id which is foreign key of user table.

the table user have around 1 million records and the post table have around 8 to 9 millions of records.

```
        $post = new Post();
        $post->setUser($user);
        $post->setPostType($posttype);
        .
        .[some more fields]
        .
        .
        $post->setStatus(1);
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();
```

I need to pass user instance to post entity. The main problem is it take long time 4 to 7 sec for insert data. It that possible that If pass the instance of user that why it take time ?. Or is there other way that I pass the user_id only instead of instance

Comment: Did you make any debugging? Symfony's profiler will tell you how long it took to execute this query. Also you will get the final query so you can run it without PHP app in order to make an investigation on DB side. I don't think it's a matter of PHP code itself.

Comment: yes, I get final query and run it in sql It is not take that much time that symfony2 take.

Comment: Then check in profiler what does take so much time. Maybe some unwanted additional select query is executed.

Comment: I don't think the querying itself takes that long; it's modifying the object(s), checking validations, creating the queries, etc. that take most of the time. Dragoste is right: check your profiler.

Comment: I put log before $em->flush() and after that. like `$logger->notice('flush start');
$em->flush()
$logger->notice('flush end');` so it take 3-4 sec for flush data. the start and end time has take 3-4 sec.

Comment: It is possible that I had pass more then 1 instance of entity ?. Like I have more 3 instance rather than user.

Comment: make `$em->flush(); $em->clear()` right before `$post = new Post();` to ensure that you are not taking much time to process changes not related to this code.